# VBA skipping code based on previous error

Tags: excel, vba

I think I am missing something obvious but have been looking at it for so long I think I may be blind to it.
I have a sheet coded to create a pivot table from a downloaded report and apply specific filters to the pivot table - which I am aware will have some instances where there is only 1 item in the filter list so cannot apply and returns an error.

I have managed to add 'On Error GoTo...' a line past the code I know will not be able to process.

However, I also have a second Pivot Table on the same sheet which applies the same filter but in reverse - i.e. the filter will usually have 2 items, so the 2 pivot tables end up showing the breakdown of the contents of each item.

The problem is 'On Error GoTo...' is not working on the second item.
I have the GoTo locations name differently - the first pivot GoTo = 'NoOKL:' and the second = 'NoOKS:'.

Because an error on the first Pivot will mean an error on the second every time I am trying to get around this by adding 'P = 1' to the error handling of the first Pivot and then added the code below for the second:

```
If P = 1 Then GoTo NoOKS

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable11").PivotFields("CATEGORY")
    .PivotItems("OKL_CONTRACTS").Visible = False
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable11").PivotFields("CATEGORY"). _
    EnableMultiplePageItems = True

NoOKS:

End If
```

I have tried moving the GoTo location 'NoOKS' both inside the If statement and outside but get the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to structure your code to never use `GoTo` - it is considered very bad practice and can lead to unmanageable code. With something like this you can just use a multi-line `If` statement to only execute that block of code if a certain condition exists.

Comment: Remove `End If` at the end ;)

Comment: You need a `Resume` statement of some kind to clear the current exception state. Otherwise any errors after the first one will be unhandled. But also pay close attention to the comment about `Goto` which should typically only appear in error handling - it would be completely unnecessary here if your code did work; you just test for inequality instead.

Comment: You might also benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what your code might look like if you omit all GoTo's.

```
If P = 1 Then
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("CATEGORY")
        .PivotItems("OKL_CONTRACTS").Visible = False
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = False
    End With
Else
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable11").PivotFields("CATEGORY")
        .PivotItems("OKL_CONTRACTS").Visible = False
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    End With
End If
```

This code presumes that you have 2 pivot tables of which you want to hide one subject to the number of items it will display (presumed to be `P`) and set the `EnableMultiplePageItems` property differently. This doesn't make much sense in the above example but the objective is to show the use of *If* and *Else* instead of *GoTo*.

I point out that `EnableMultiplePageItems = (P = 1)` would also set the property to either *True* or *False* depending upon the evaluation of the statement `(P = 1)`. In the above example the property belongs to different objects but if you have to set the same property for the same object to different values in your project depending upon the value of *P* that method will avoid even the use of `If`, not to mention `GoTo` and reduce the amount of code as well.